# Is It More Efficient to Do a Less Than comparison OR a Less Than Or Equal To?

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, compiler-construction, operators

I'm wondering if it's more efficient to do a less than or equal to comparison in a loop or a less than comparison. Does the `<=` operator instruct the computer to make two comparisons (is it less than, is it equal to), or does it simplify it? Take the following example. I want a loop than increments to 1000. Should I set the ceiling to 1001 and tell it that `while i is < (OR !=) 1001, i++;`? Or should I tell it that `while i <= 1000, i++;`? Will the compiler (GCC) simplify it to the same basic instructions?

Comment: Both use machine-level instructions. It makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: If possible, it's more efficient to run the loop backwards so that you can test `i` against 0 instead of a constant.

Comment: How would that be cheaper?

Comment: @chepner, wow that's something new to me, how's it more efficient? because we only need to retrieve i once?

Comment: @chepner yes, but it runs into the realm of micro-optimization. You will then have to worry about whether the CPU is correctly pre-fetching for the data cache when running backwards (it does, but the parameters might be different than prefetching from ascending addresses.) So many things to worry about that I wouldn't worry about it unless benchmark tells me otherwise.

Comment: It may be architecture-dependent, but there is often an opcode specifically for testing if a value is zero, rather than having to compare it to an arbitrary bit pattern.

Comment: @wafflesausage: It appears that testing against zero would make a special case; otherwise any other value would be pretty much the same. It does make sense to copy the sentinel to a local variable: if you check against, say, `std::vector::size()`, in practice it does incur one or more memory read, although the cost is trivial if your loop is not empty.

Comment: @chepner: yes, on x86, it would be `TEST` versus `CMP`.

Comment: For X86, it's possible that while((--i) != 0) is faster, because a decrement (or a subtract) sets the flag bits, eliminating the need for a compare to value (or effectively compare or test for zero). In the case of Visual Studio 2005, assume ecx is "i", then it sets eax to 1, and the two instruction sequence is | sub eax,ecx | jnz ... | to do the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the architecture.

The original von Neumann IAS architecture (1945) did have only `>=` comparison.

Intel 8086 can use `Loop label` paradigm, which corresponds to `do { } while (--cx > 0);`
In legacy architectures, `LOOP` was not only smaller, but faster. In modern architectures  `LOOP` is considered complex operation, which is slower than `dec ecx; jnz label;` When optimizing for size (-Os) this can still have significance.

Further considerations are that some (RISC) architectures do not have explicit flag registers. Then comparison can't be given free, as a side effect of loop decrement. Some RISC architectures have also a special 'zero' register, which means, that comparison (and every other mathematical operations) with zero is always available. RISCs with *jump delay slots* may even benefit from using post decrement: `do { } while (a-- > 0);`

An optimizing compiler should be able to convert a simple loop regardless of the syntax to the most optimized version for the given architecture. A complex loop would have a dependency to the iterator, side effects, or both: `for (i=0;i<5;i++) func(i);`.

Answer (score 9):

The machine level architecture will have OP codes for both < and <= operations and both comparisons can be made in one cycle of the CPU. Meaning it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Measure it. Only then you can be absolutely sure which is faster.

You may think a lot about all the parts that play a role here (compiler, optimisation, processor, etc.). But in the end it is faster if it takes less time. It's as simple as that.